# I want to scrape all the text data from a page of website if that page contains some specific word.. But this code s showing errors

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib2, ubuntu-14.04

I want to scrape all the text data from a website's page if that page contains some specific words.I have written this code to collect the data from a page if that page contains searchphrase.. but it id giving error after running..

```
  import urllib2    
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup       
  import urlparse    
  import html2text       
  import re                                                                

  yoururl=raw_input('Enter your url:')    
  page=urllib2.urlopen('http://'+ yoururl)    
  soup=BeautifulSoup(page)          

  for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):     
      raw=tag['href']     
      b1=urlparse.urlparse(tag['href']).hostname     
      b2=urlparse.urlparse(tag['href']).path           
      fulllink=str(b1)+str(b2)       
      html=urllib2.urlopen(fulllink)                
      h = html2text.HTML2Text()     
      h.ignore_links= True            
      if "searchphrase" in h.html:            
         print h.handle(html)
```

Comment: managed to fix your program quit quickly to do something.  Not sure it's what you want or if I am using the same versions of the libraries as you are so I won't post the solution

Comment: Oh, the two main problems are "fulllink" needs an 'http://' in front of it and the bit that is supposed to get the raw html page with html2text seems a bit off

Comment: can you please post the solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed above this might not be exactly what the OP intended

This program takes 
a start url.  It then finds hrefs in the page.  Does some pointless manipulation on the hrefs that ICBA to refactor :) and retrieves the objects that the hrefs point to.

Finally, if the data in the object retrieved contains a magic key word (in my case "winter") then the object is displayed

The depth of searching is only one deep, unlike a proper crawler

```
import urllib2    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup       
import urlparse    

yoururl=raw_input('Enter your url:')    
page=urllib2.urlopen('http://'+ yoururl)    
soup=BeautifulSoup(page)          

for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):     
      raw=tag['href']     
      b1=urlparse.urlparse(tag['href']).hostname     
      b2=urlparse.urlparse(tag['href']).path           
      fulllink=str(b1)+str(b2)       
      html=urllib2.urlopen('http://' + fulllink).readlines()                
      if "winter" in repr(html):            
         print html
```

Comment: its working,thanks man, but the problem is it is giving the whole html souce page.. what if I want to get only the texts from the htmlsource ignoring the links and html related symbols